# Axios call getting blocked due to CORS error

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I have a react application with server side rendering using Express server . I want to make a POST request using axios but it is getting blocked with CORS error :
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xyz/abc' from origin 'http://localhost:4249' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried after adding allow origin headers and cors module in my server call but that didn't work

```
    import cors from "cors";
const server = express();
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
server.use(express.static("dist"));
server.use(cors());
```

Here is the axios request :

```
const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "x-ms-version": "2019-07-11",
    Authorization: token,
    "x-ms-date": date,
    "x-ms-documentdb-isquery": true,
    "Content-Type": "application/query+json",
    "x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition": "true",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(
        "https://xyz/abc",
        data,
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        setres(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Webpack Config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: why are you communicating `HTTPS`:xyz with  `HTTP` localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before, and this is just what I did:

**app.js (backend)**

```
server.use(cors({
  origin: '<YOUR_FRONTEND_URL_PATH>',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  credentials: true
}));
```

**axios request:**

```
const resp = await axios.post(
     apiUrl,
     params,
     {
        withCredentials: true,
        timeout: 10000
     }
);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me . Still getting same error